# Calculate numbers in file by bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have file with the following content.
 e.g.  2 images with FRAGMENT size. I want to calculate the fragments total size in bash script.

```
IMAGE admindb1 8 admindb1_1514997916 bus 4 Default-Application-Backup 2 3 1 1517676316 0 0
FRAG 1 1 10784 0 2 6 2 HSBRQ2 fuj 65536 329579 1514995208 60 0 *NULL* 1517676316 0 3 1 *NULL*

IMAGE admindb1 8 admindb1_1514995211 bus 4 Default-Application-Backup 2 3 1 1517673611 0 0
FRAG 1 1 13168256 0 2 6 12 HSBQ8I fuj 65536 173783 1514316708 52 0 *NULL* 1517673611 0 3 1 *NULL*
FRAG 1 2 24288384 0 2 6 1 HSBRJ7 fuj 65536 2 1514995211 65 0 *NULL* 0 0 3 1 *NULL*
FRAG 1 3 24288384 0 2 6 1 HSBRON fuj 65536 2 1514995211 71 0 *NULL* 0 0 3 1 *NULL*
FRAG 1 4 13806752 0 2 6 1 HSBRRK fuj 65536 2 1514995211 49 0 *NULL* 0 0 3 1 *NULL*
```

Output should be like this:

```
For Image admindb1_1514997916  total size is 10784
For Image  admindb1_1514995211  total size is 75551776
```

4th column at line which is  beginning with FRAG should be calculated.

My script is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash 
file1=/home/turgun/Desktop/IBteck/script-last/frags 
imagelist=/home/turgun/Desktop/IBteck/script-last/imagelist 
counter=1 
for counter in `cat $imagelist` 
do 
     n=`awk '/'$counter'/{ print NR; exit }' $file1`
     for n in `cat $file1` 
     do 
          if [[ ! $n = 'IMAGE' ]]; then 
              echo "For Image $counter total size is " \
                   `grep FRAG frags | awk '{print total+=$4}'`  
          fi 
     done 
done
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How is this related to javascript?

Comment: Do you `echo` the the result to JavaScript?

Comment: Also: which of the column is the sizes you want to sum? Should we be guessing?

Comment: mistyped by tagging the javascript

Comment: Thank you meta, for remind.  4th columnt at FRAG line should be calculated

Comment: @TurgunDuishonali, why should this fragment `FRAG 1 1 13168256 ...` should be missed? The output for the 2nd image is `For image admindb1_1514995211 total size is 75551776`

Comment: I wrote as an example. You are right. I will correct it to avoid ,leading to puzzle.

Comment: My script is not working

Comment: #!/bin/bash
file1=/home/turgun/Desktop/IBteck/script-last/frags
imagelist=/home/turgun/Desktop/IBteck/script-last/imagelist
counter=1

for counter in `cat $imagelist`
do
 n=`awk '/'$counter'/{ print NR; exit }' $file1`
    for n in `cat $file1`
     do 
       if [[ !  $n = 'IMAGE' ]]; then
 echo "For Image $counter   total size is "
 grep FRAG frags | awk '{print total+=$4}'
 fi
     done
done

Comment: more /home/turgun/Desktop/IBteck/script-last/imagelist
admindb1_1514997916
admindb1_1514995211

Comment: more /home/turgun/Desktop/IBteck/script-last/frags
IMAGE admindb1 8 admindb1_1514997916 bus 4 Default-Application-Backup 2 3 1 1517676316 0 0
FRAG 1 1 10784 0 2 6 2 HSBRQ2 fuj 65536 329579 1514995208 60 0 *NULL* 1517676316 0 3 1 *NULL*

IMAGE admindb1 8 admindb1_1514995211 bus 4 Default-Application-Backup 2 3 1 1517673611 0 0
FRAG 1 1 13168256 0 2 6 12 HSBQ8I fuj 65536 173783 1514316708 52 0 *NULL* 1517673611 0 3 1 *NULL*

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'function summary() {print "For Image",image,"total size is",sum} 
     $1=="IMAGE" {image=$4}                         
     $1=="FRAG" {sum+=$4} 
     $1=="" {summary(); sum=0}
     END{summary()}' file
```

Output:

```
For Image admindb1_1514997916 total size is 10784
For Image admindb1_1514995211 total size is 75551776
```

I assume that the last line is not empty.

Comment: Hi Cyrus, Thank you for support. Just one question.Actually in file without blank space.What can we write instead of it ? ($1=="").  There are more than  thousand of line like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat -s file.txt | sed -n '/^IMAGE /{s:^[^ ]*  *[^ ]*  *[^ ]*  *\([^ ]*\).*$:echo -n "For image \1 total size is "; echo `echo ":;s:\*::g;p};/^$/{s:^:0"`|bc:;p};/^FRAG /{s:^[^ ]*  *[^ ]*  *[^ ]*  *\([^ ]*\).*$:\1\+:;s:\*::g;p};' | bash
```

Output:

```
For image admindb1_1514997916 total size is 10784
For image admindb1_1514995211 total size is 75551776
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^IMAGE/{ 
         if (t) { printf "For image %s total size is %d\n",img,t; t=0 } img=$4 
     }
     /^FRAG/{ t+=$4 }
     END{ if (t) printf "For image %s total size is %d\n",img,t }' file
```

The output:

```
For image admindb1_1514997916 total size is 10784
For image admindb1_1514995211 total size is 75551776
```

Comment: You also the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Gnarly combo of `cut`, *GNU* `sed`, (with a careless use of `e`*valuate*), and [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/):

```
cut -d' ' -f4 file | datamash --no-strict transpose | 
sed 's#\tN/A\t#\n#g;y#\t# #' | 
sed 's/ \(.*\)/ $((\1))/;y/ /+/;s/+/ /;
     s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/echo For image \1  total size is \2/e'
```

Output:

```
For image admindb1_1514997916 total size is 10784
For image admindb1_1514995211 total size is 75551776
```

---

[*Cyrus's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48254333/6136214) is just better.  This answer shows some limits of `sed`.  Also if the data file is huge, (say millions of numbers to sum), the `e`*valuate* used to farm out the addition to the shell would probably exceed its command line length limit.